# Applying major-mode font locking to exported org-babel snippets

Tags: org-mode, org-export, syntax-highlighting, org-babel

Currently I have a bunch of code snippets in my Org-based presentation. I'm exporting them with `ox-reveal`, but the exported code doesn't have any syntax highlighting. Is there any way to:

1. have syntax highlighting in code blocks in org-mode?
2. ensure that the syntax highlighting is carried through to the exported HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable syntax highlighting of code blocks in org-mode by setting `org-src-fontify-natively` to `t`.

That will probably not help exporting to ox-reveal. In any case "normal" HTML export syntax highlighting (without ox-reveal) is enabled by default if you have `htmlize.el` installed, so it may be worthwile checking if you have htmlize installed. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082430/org-mode-no-syntax-highlighting-in-exported-html-page)

Comment: Indeed it does, I had been using #+begin_example instead of #+begin_src with the language spec.